# cordova where permission can come from?

Tags: android, cordova

I installed the latest pushwoosh-cordova-plugin plugin
and looking at my app permissions I can see that after installing it ask for READ_PHONE_STATE.

The problem is looking at the [plugin plugin.xml file](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml) I cant find any info about this permission

so where can it come from?
cant find any info about where plugin can ask for permissions from on the cordova docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out that its was bug in [google play services they fix it in 10.0.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_2016_-_v100)

pushwoosh using google play service so that's why I saw that permissions

> Google Play services updated to 10.0.1 This release fixes a missing
>   minSdkVersion value in play-services-location.aar that caused
>   unintended WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and
>   READ_PHONE_STATE permissions to be merged into app manifests.